# I can't get my Svelte App to compile with "npm run dev"

Tags: svelte

I ran NPM Update on an App that I have not worked on in a couple of months. Now it won't build.

I don't know what to try, a little help please!!!

```
PS C:\Dev2019\ticketssql\tickets-sap> npm run dev

> tickets@1.37.64 dev C:\Dev2019\ticketssql\tickets-sap
> update-v -p && sapper dev

+ "tickets" -> v1.37.65
✗ server
Could not resolve entry module (undefined\server.js).
✗ client
Could not resolve entry module (undefined\client.js).
✗ service worker
Could not resolve entry module (undefined\service-worker.js).
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Dev2019\ticketssql\tickets-sap\__sapper__\dev\server\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
> Server crashed
```

Comment: Not sure which Sapper version you were upgrading from, but does https://sapper.svelte.dev/migrating help at all?

Comment: To make it worse, after this happens, things stay broken even for commits that used to work...

Comment: If you're using dynamic imports, there's an issue with that working between `npm run dev` and `build`. So try to remove all the dynamic imports or any imports that has weird static path in it and see if it fixes your issue

Comment: It feels like a node version related problem. Switch with nvm for a try